# POSIX guaranteeing write to disk

Tags: c, file-io, io, posix, storage

As I understand it, if I want to synchronise data to the storage device I can use fsync() to supposedly flush all the OS output caches... but apparently it doesn't guarantee this at all, unlike the documentation tries to deceive you, and the data may not be written to the disk!

This is not very good for many purposes because it can lead to data corruption. How do I use the POSIX libraries (In a portable way if possible) to guarantee that the data has been written (as far as possible) and prevent data corruption?

There is fdatasync() but it is not implemented on OSX, so is there a better and more portable way, or does one have to implement different code on different systems? I'm also not sure if fdatasync() is good enough.

Of-course, in the worst case scenario I could forget about this and use a redundant database library that uses ACID to store the data. I don't want that.

Also I'm interested in how to ensure truncate and rename operations have definitely completed.

Thanks!

Comment: You could try the [`sync`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/sync.2.html) system call instead?

Comment: Don't try to be smarter than the operating system. The OS and its file system know best how to prevent data corruption.

Comment: Nikes C. Well I'm not trying to be smarter than the operating system, I'm trying to be smart enough to understand the operating systems. If they can prevent data corruption, I want to know how. A simple fsync() doesn't appear good enough.

Comment: If you want to understand operating systems then you should write one.  But the point you have reached here is of trying to understand hard drive firmware, which is lower level than the system OS.  Once the bits are on the drive the hard drive decides when and in which order to put them on the platter.  Since there is so much data flying around the hard drive will try to organize its writes in the most efficient way possible.

Comment: OSX proves that operating systems can tell storage devices to write their cache to permanent storage (Not necessarily a HDD platter since it could be an SSD). Whether or not other operating systems can easily do this is another matter.

Comment: I am looking for similar function call.  I wonder whether you have found anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for sync.  There is both a program called sync and a system call called sync (`man 1 sync` and `man 2 sync` respectively):

```
   #include <unistd.h>

   void sync(void);

DESCRIPTION
   sync() first commits inodes to buffers, and then buffers to disk.
```

So it will ensure that all pending operations (truncates, renames etc) are in fact written to the disk.

`fsync` does not claim to flush all output caches, but instead claims to flush all changes to a particular file descriptor to disk.  It explicitly does not ensure that the directory entry is updated (in which case a call to fsync on a filedescriptor for the directory is needed).

`fsyncdata` is even more useless as it will not flush file metadata and instead will just ensure that the data in the file is flushed.

It is a good idea to trust the manpages.  I won't say there are not mistakes, but they tend to be extremely accurate.

Comment: OK, thanks. sync() sounds like it provides the required guarantee that the operations have completed. Though waiting for all pending IO operations to complete seems inefficient. Is there a way to process and wait only for the specific operations required by the program?

Comment: You would have to call fsync on every fd that is of importance, plus open fds on all of the directories of importance and call fsync on those too.

Comment: On OSX it says: "Note that while fsync() will flush all data from the host to the drive (i.e. the "permanent
     storage device"), the drive itself may not physically write the data to the platters for quite
     some time and it may be written in an out-of-order sequence.

     Specifically, if the drive loses power or the OS crashes, the application may find that only
     some or none of their data was written.  The disk drive may also re-order the data so that
     later writes may be present, while earlier writes are not." So does fsync()ing the directories solve that problem?

Comment: No it will not fix that problem.  The hard drive will attempt to write your data as soon as possible though.  What is the situation where you need to know if the data is physically on the platter?

Comment: Well OSX does have this: "For applications that require tighter guarantees about the integrity of their data, Mac OS X
     provides the F_FULLFSYNC fcntl.  The F_FULLFSYNC fcntl asks the drive to flush all buffered
     data to permanent storage.  Applications, such as databases, that require a strict ordering of
     writes should use F_FULLFSYNC to ensure that their data is written in the order they expect.
     Please see fcntl(2) for more detail." So I was wondering if there was a portable way of achieving the same guarantees.

Comment: And I need this to implement something similar to database transactions, except I'm using my own type of storage and indexing. As I've said, I could always use a database library and store the data that way but there is no need for that. I certainly don't need a relational database for what I'm doing.

Comment: You might want to look at some sort of NoSQL or Berkeley DB type database system.  Implementing this sort of thing is hard and unless the database IS the project, you probably shouldn't be doing it yourself.

Comment: I might look at a very simple and efficient database. I do not need SQL and from what I hear they waste a lot of disk space and IO operations. Something like levelDB might be OK for implementing basic key-value storage though I've heard from people that it might not be perfect for maintaining data integrity. Hmmm.

Comment: It sounds like you are on the right track.  Find something that meets your requirements and go with that.  If all you need is a key/value store then go for that.  There are also options like mongoDB if you need something a little more advanced.